# Input element in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How to set the size or width of an input element in javascript.

I am using `input_obj.size= '40%'`;

But, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use style attribute:

```
  input_obj.style.width = '40%';
```

Comment: This is working fine in IE, but not in firefox..Any Suggestions for firefox..?

Answer (score 2):

You set the size as per your own example — but it doesn't take a CSS length. It takes an integer (number of characters).

The width is set as per any other element: `input_obj.style.width`.

Answer (score 0):

If input_obj is your input obj (which I assume according to the name ;))

```
input_obj.style.width = '100px';
```